# MailKit receive emails doesn't show message.Body

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mailkit

I'm receiving emails OK, except that `message.TextBody` is showing a blank when there is a message present.
`message.HtmlBody` shows the body text amongst a whole lot of html stuff, obviously, but I'm looking for `message.TextBody`.

`message.TextBody.ToString()` shows an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I'm using the following code:

```cs
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
client.Authenticate("aaaa@gmail.com", "ssss");

gstrEmailMessages = gstrEmailMessages + client.Count + "\n";

//Fetch emails:
for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
{
    var message = client.GetMessage(i);
    gstrEmailMessages = gstrEmailMessages + "Subject: " + message.Subject + "\n";
    gstrEmailMessages = gstrEmailMessages + "TextBody: " + message.TextBody + "\n";
    gstrEmailMessages = gstrEmailMessages + "HtmlBody: " + message.HtmlBody + "\n";
}

//Disconnect connection:
client.Disconnect(true);
```

Why does `message.TextBody` show a blank?

Comment: I would assume that's because the message is in HTML and does not contain a text only version.  Have you tried sending a plain text e-mail?

Comment: That would make sense! Sometimes, an answer is in the real world, and not in code!

Answer (score 1):

Not all messages will have both an HTML and a plain-text body. In fact, it's possible for some messages to have neither.

In general, though, most messages will have at least 1 of those.